# Unable to construct appropriate linq-to-sql query

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

I'm having trouble coming up with the right linq to sql query for the problem below.

I have 3 tables:

A) "Product" with the following columns:

- productID: unique identifier
- pageID: identifier of the page for the product
- companyID: identifier of the company that owns the product

B) "Company" with the following columns:

- companyID: unique identifier of the company
- pageID: identifier of the page for the company

C) "Page" with  the following columns:

- pageID: unique identifier of the page
- parentID: id of the parent page (basically, a company can own another company, and this is where it is maintained)
  [image: SQL diagram]

One thing is that the *companyID* in the **Product** table is equal to the *pageID* in the **Company** table

This is mainly to know the URL of the company that owns the product (FYI, this is the schema I have to work with, so I can't really modify it unfortunately).

What I'm trying to achieve is:
The user will have a form and will enter the name of a company in a textbox, and I need to be able to retrieve the list of products that are owned by that company.

I'm able to do that when there are no parent companies:

```
from p in ctx.Products
join c in ctx.Companies on p.pageID equals c.companyID
where ...
select ...
```

However, if a company has a parent (defined in the Page table), I'm not sure how to go about that? Is that another join statement??

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this would be writing a view (or stored proc) and importing it into your model instead of writing a linq query(s) to do this.  The sql query (most likely using a common table expression [or CTE]) would be way better in terms of performance.  Try writing a view (or stored proc) with a CTE.  This will allow you to recursively query the database.

Edit:  This is a start (I'm not a dedicated SQL expert, so this may or may not work on first run)

```
WITH CTECompanyProducts(pageID
                      , parentID
                      , pageName
                      , companyID
                      , companyFieldA
                      , companyFieldB
                      , companyFieldC
                      , productFieldA
                      , productFieldB
                      , productFieldC
                      , level)
AS
(
    SELECT p.pageID
         , p.parentID
         , p.pageName
         , c.companyID
         , c.fieldA
         , c.fieldB
         , c.fieldC
         , pr.field1
         , pr.field2
         , pr.field3
         , 0 AS Level
    FROM Page p
    JOIN Company c
        ON p.pageID = c.pageID
    JOIN Product pr
        ON pr.companyID = c.companyID
    WHERE p.parentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT p.pageID
         , p.parentID
         , p.pageName
         , c.companyID
         , c.fieldA
         , c.fieldB
         , c.fieldC
         , pr.field1
         , pr.field2
         , pr.field3
         , Level + 1
    FROM Page p
    JOIN Company c
        ON p.pageID = c.pageID
    JOIN Product pr
        ON pr.companyID = c.companyID
    JOIN Page pa
        ON p.pageID = pa.parentID
)

SELECT *
FROM CTECompanyProducts
Where companyID = [your company ID];
```

Comment: Hey Kenny, thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately, I'm not even sure how to write the SQL query to create the view for this requirement.. any help with that? Thanks

Comment: Yo, I made an edit .. I am not sure if it's going to work initially but its a start.  You can search for recursive CTE for more help